# Migrating a Java ee 6 with hibernate, lucene from JBossAS 7 to Wildfly 9

Tags: hibernate, jboss7.x, jpa-2.0, wildfly, hibernate-search

I have a Java EE 6 application with Hibernate 4.1.1, JPA 2.0, with Lucene indexes stored on the filesystem. I am trying to migrate this to WildFLy 9.0.1. I understand that Hibernate Search is now part of WildFly and it gets started by default. I used the jboss-deployement-structure.xml load my specific versions but not having any luck. Does anyone have experience with this. This is my Maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.CR2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
        <version>4.10.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the JPA API, we use provided scope as the API is included in
        JBoss AS 7 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
       <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- jca jboss specific -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>            
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And this is the jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
<deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.hibernate.search.orm" services="export"/>
        <module name="org.hibernate.search.engine" services="export"/>
    </dependencies>
</deployment>

<sub-deployment name="my-ejb-project.jar">
    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.hibernate.search.orm" services="export"/>
        <module name="org.hibernate.search.engine" services="export"/>
        <module name="org.apache.lucene" services="export"/>
    </dependencies>
</sub-deployment>
```

In the standalone.xml I set the system property "enableHibernateSearch" to true and indexDir is defined as well.

During WildFly startup I see this:
[org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Skipping Hibernate Search event listener auto registration

Why is the Search event listener not getting registered.

And when I invoke search 
org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000222: The SearchFactory was not initialized

What do I need to do to get the SearchFactory initialized.

Comment: Is there a reason you're tying to use 4.1.1.Final of Hibernate? WildFly 9.0.1.Final uses [4.3.10.Final](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/9.0.1.Final/pom.xml#L139-L144). I wouldn't advise trying to override the version the container provides if you want the container to manage JPA for you.

Comment: @james, thank you, I updated the dependencies to use 4.3.10.Final. I now get this error when I try to use the search "org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000222: The SearchFactory was not initialized"

Comment: All the Hibernate dependencies should be marked as `<scope>provided</scope>` since they're provided by the container. And on't use the exclusions in the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`.

Comment: Also make sure to compile the project using the same version of Hibernate Search as WildFly 9.0.1.Final: version 5.2.0.Final https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/9.0.1.Final/pom.xml#L144 (and also mark it as provided)

Comment: Thank you @Sanne, I updated the dependencies, and the jboss-deployment-structure file, now I get a different error listed above:  HSEARCH000222: The SearchFactory was not initialized

Comment: Do you have any entity marked @Indexed ? The Search system won't be started - nor registered within Hibernate ORM - if your entities are not making use of it.

Comment: @Vijay, could you double-check that you don't accidentally set "enableHibernateSearch" to false? I am asking because AFAICS you only should get the message "Skipping..." from withingHibernateSearchIntegrator if that property is set to false.